# How to create a batch file that read parameters from another file

Tags: batch-file, parameters, parameter-passing, configuration-files

omeone help me to create a batch file that read 3 Parameters from another file e.g. Config.conf in same directory?

The Config file contains following information:

```
--url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.0.91:1521:xe" --username=TestUser01 --password=passowrd01
```

I need to set 3 Prameters %url% , %username% , %pwd% in my MIG.bat file, which are working with there parameters.

Thanks and regards

Comment: How your config file looks like?

Comment: --url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.0.91:1521:xe" --username=TestUser01 --password=passowrd01

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If everything is on one line and in the same order...

```
@echo off
setlocal
    set "cfgFile=c:\test.cfg"

    for /f "tokens=2,4,6 delims==- " %%a in ('type "%cfgFile%"^| find /i "url"') do (
        set "URL=%%~a"
        set "user=%%~b"
        set "pass=%%~c"
    )

    echo %URL% %user% %pass%
endlocal
```

Answer (score 0):

I have now a second solution as well.

I have changed the Config.conf:

```
--url = jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.0.91:1521:xe"
--username=TestUser01
--password=passowrd01
```

my test.bat:

```
@echo off
setlocal
    for /f "usebackq tokens=1 delims=--" %%A in ("%cd%\config.conf") do (
        set "%%A"
    )
    echo %url%
    echo %username%
    echo %password%
endlocal
```